# How to disable some plugins of adobe-reader X?

Tags: windows, plugins, adobe-reader

There are a lot of plug-ins (I mean not a browser plugin to view pdfs, but plugins of reader itself, e.g. for internet access, commenting a pdf, javascript in pdf, 3d in pdf and so on) pre installed with "Adobe Reader X", almost 25. Some of them are annoying, some of them are unsafe to be enabled (e.g. Adobe Multimedia plug-ins allows PDF files to use built-in Flash, which is usually outdated and vulnerable in any version; ECMAScript may be vulnerable; Comments are annoying and never-will-use-it for me).

I want to completely turn off some of Adobe Reader X plug-ins. Also, it would be perfect if this setting will be saved in case of Adobe Reader update with newer version.

PS Adobe Reader X  = Adobe reader 10 (more exactly version 10.1); OS is Windows (any supported by AR X  version)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, an answer (Googled in 20 seconds):

http://help.adobe.com/archive/en_US/acrobat/9/standard/acrobat_standard_9.0_help.pdf

> ### Manage plug-ins
>
> Plug-ins add more functionality, but they also increase the memory needed [<strike>**and security risks**</strike>](https://superuser.com/posts/322789/edit). To minimize memory requirements, you may want to install only the plug-ins that you use. To load a plug-in correctly, you must place it in the plug-ins folder. You can temporarily disable plug-ins when starting your software.
>
> #### Disable a plug-in
>
> 1. Do one of the following:
>
>    - (Windows) Open the plug_ins folder (Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat\plug_ins).
>    - (Mac OS) Control-click the application icon, and choose Show Package Contents. Then double-click the Contents folder and open the Plug-ins folder.
>    - (UNIX) Move the plug-in out of [location of install]/Adobe/Reader9.0/Reader/plug_ins.
> 2. Select the plug-ins you do not want to load, and move them out of the folder. Some of the plug-ins may be in folders nested inside the plug-ins folder.
>
> #### Disable all plug-ins temporarily
>
> - Press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key immediately after starting Acrobat.